# Read Only folder alias in Windows

Tags: windows, mount, alias

I have a folder I would like to create a read only alias of to prevent tools from modifying the original contents in any way. The original should be kept in "pristine" condition so subsequent or parallel runs of tools cannot modify contents in any way. No updating existing files, creating new files (e.g. logs), or deleting files.

i.e. I have `D:\data`. I would have `D:\dataRO1` which is an alias of `D:\data`, but any modifications would be prohibited. The actual folder structure is `D:\data\typeA`, `D:\data\typeB`, and `D:\dataRO1\temp` which is the one folder exception for which full permission could be allowed to.

I don't see a problem of creating multiple aliases (e.g. `D:\dataRO1\typeA` to alias `D:\data\typeA`, same for type B and C) and creating a real `D:\dataRO1\temp` as there are only a few folders in the "root". I do see a problem of creating hundreds of thousands of read only links by walking the tree.

Is it possible on Windows to create a read only "mount" or alias of an existing folder?

Comment: Windows does not respect the read-only attribute very well, and pretty much ignores it for folders. Perhaps you can set *ownership* of the folder so that other users or processes cannot alter it, using ICACLS: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3587-change-owner-file-folder-drive-registry-key-windows-10-a.html and https://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html

Comment: Does this help : [Read-only NTFS junction point or symlink](https://superuser.com/questions/881544/read-only-ntfs-junction-point-or-symlink)?

Comment: You have to configure the NTFS security properly for the security context of the application at execution time, then it will work as expected with respect to the "app" having read-only to data within the folder. It works flawlessly if configured properly, then having a symlink or creating a share and mounting to it is the other part of the configuration. Sounds like lockdown is the most important point you seek though. You can do with with ICACLS or just the right click properties. Understanding the security context the app runs as, is an important point to not overlook as well.